# Euro symbol in GBK encoded Chinese language page

Tags: java, html, encoding

i have a page that is rendering words in Chinese characters. I am using the GBK encoding, and i am able to display and save Chinese characters successfully on my html page.

User input of the Euro symbol was successful, but there is a problem when saving it. When my Java server side code grabs the request, the form data has changed the euro symbol to a question mark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there *is* no Euro symbol in GBK. For example, from the [code page 936 wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_936):

> The concept "CP936", "GBK" and "GB2312" are sometimes confused in various software products. Code page 936 is not identical to GBK because a code page encodes characters while the GBK only defines code points. In addition, the Euro sign (€), encoded as 0x80 in CP936, is not defined in GBK.

So basically, if you want to encode the Euro symbol, you should pick a different encoding. (Any reason you don't want to use UTF-8 or UTF-16? They may be less efficient, but at least you'll then be able to represent all Unicode characters...)

Comment: if i use UTF8 or UTF16, i can no longer view my Chinese characters

Comment: Well you certainly *should* be able to - if you can't, you're doing something wrong (e.g. specifying the wrong encoding in headers).